# I cant generate URL with router service when JMSI18nRoutingBundle is in use - Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, routes

```php
$this->getServiceContainer()->get('router')->getGenerator()->generate('ting_user_reset_password', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

When I try to generate a URL with the `router` service using the route name `ting_user_reset_password` an exception occurs because with JMSI18nRoutingBundle the route name doesnt exist.

```php
 /**
 * @Route("/reset-password", name="ting_user_reset_password")
 * @Template()
 */
public function resetPasswordAction(){

}
```

JMSI18nRoutingBundle create the following routes:

```
us_US_RG_ting_user_reset_password
de_DE_RG_ting_user_reset_password
es_ES_RG_ting_user_reset_password
...
```

If you disable JMSI18nRoutingBundle for this route, the router service works fine:

```php
 /**
 * @Route("/reset-password", name="ting_user_reset_password", options={"i18n" = false})
 * @Template()
 */
public function resetPasswordAction(){

}
```

---

How can I get the URL using the router service by specifying the name of the route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made many tests and the correct way to generate urls when the bundle "JMSI18nRoutingBundle" is used, is as follows :

```
$this->getServiceContainer()->get('router')->generate('ting_user_reset_password', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

without `getGenerator()->`

thats working fine to me.